# Why is my Nativescript worker slowing a heavy process?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, worker, nativescript-angular

I have an application that does some intensive work at some point, which blocks the UI for about 10seconds. As the loading animations and my services are on the main thread, I've decided to make use of nativescript workers. The UI no longer freezes, but the process is taking much more time (100s v.s. 10s).

*Does somebody have an idea about what is wrong ?*

my `worker.ts` is quite simple :

```
import "tns-core-modules/globals";
import { DatabaseService } from "../services/database.service";

const context: Worker = self as any;
const databaseService: DatabaseService = new DatabaseService();

context.onmessage = msg => {
      databaseService.fillWithMissions(msg.data).then((n:number)=>{     
            (<any>global).postMessage("test");
        });
};
```

When the postMessage is received on my component I call another similar worker after terminating this one and that's all. It takes about 100s to run both.

If I call my `databaseService.fillWithMissions()` method from the main component, UI freezes but it takes about 10sec to run both methods.

Comment: What you exactly do within your worker - `databaseService.fillWithMissions()`.

Comment: I insert some data into a Sqlite database (c.f. [module here](https://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-sqlite) ). I'll link the exact sql method in a couple hours.

Comment: How many transactions you do? Did you try running batch operations? What's the size of your DB after processing the request?

Comment: I've tested with many configurations, changing the number of items, thus transactions, and the batch size, but still the problem I have. 
I've tried batch sizes (1,5,50,100,500), with about 600 items (90% of the items are just 3 columns string).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get to my code today. but fillWithMissions method is a simple loop for on the number of items with a  sql 'insert' item inside. I'll check the DB size difference and report

Comment: Yes, please whenever you have the details. I haven't had performance issues with 5-10k records. Another workaround is to prepare your database fully, bundle with app and copy the file at runtime.

Comment: Weirdly I don't have the problem anymore. I trimmed the process a bit before posting here and the old one was probably still cached when I tested. It may explain why I experienced those poor performances. I'm surprised by the difference still, and now I can't even reproduce when going back ...